# mysql matching multiple and's and or's

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get rows from a table where there are matches on multiple other tables.

This is the query I am running.

```
SELECT qt.*, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(up.DOB, '%m-%d-%Y')) / 365 AS Age
FROM UserProfile AS up, Game AS g, QuestionTable AS qt
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Options WHERE UserID = 75 AND QID = qt.QID AND DateTime >= CURDATE())
AND g.Active = 1 AND g.QID = qt.QID
AND (((g.Gender = up.Gender OR g.Gender = 'B') AND ((g.City = up.City AND g.Zip = up.Zip AND g.Country = up.Country) OR g.Home = 0) AND ((Age BETWEEN g.Maximum AND g.Minimum) OR g.Age = 0) AND ((SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( g.Latitude - -93.5746359 ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( 44.9737707 - g.Longitude ) * COS( g.Latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) > g.Distance) OR g.Geo = 0)) OR g.Special = 0)
GROUP BY qt.QID
```

I have ran this expression through C# and it returns true, yet it is only matching on the 'g.Special = 0' part through MySql.

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by fixing some mistakes I made and changed the query to this,

```
SELECT *
FROM QuestionTable AS qt
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM Options WHERE UserID = 75 AND QID = qt.QID AND DateTime >= CURDATE())
AND EXISTS(SELECT g.* FROM UserProfile AS up, Game AS g WHERE g.Active = 1 AND g.QID = qt.QID AND(g.Special = 0 OR(
(g.Gender = up.Gender OR g.Gender = 'B') AND
((g.City = up.City AND g.zip = up.Zip AND g.Country = up.Country) OR g.Home = 0) AND 
((SQRT( POW( 69.1 * ( g.Latitude - 44.9737707 ) , 2 ) + POW( 69.1 * ( -93.5746359 - g.Longitude ) * COS( g.Latitude / 57.3 ) , 2 ) ) < g.Distance) OR g.Geo = 0) AND 
((DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, STR_TO_DATE(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y'))/365.25 BETWEEN g.Minimum AND g.Maximum) OR g.Age = 0))))
```